# Using Diffmerge with TortoiseSVN - how to deal with a single block of code (1000+ lines) that's marked as conflicted

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, diffmerge

I'm merging some changes from trunk back into a branch with TortoiseSVN. I did some whitespace modification (just tidying things up) and DiffMerge is showing a very large block of code (probably around 2000 lines) as conflicted. Some of it's just the whitespace, but some of it's also actual changes on both files.

Since DiffMerge has marked this as one large conflict, instead of a series of smaller conflicts, is there a way I can cherry-pick individual lines from each file to merge into the center? I've tried selecting only a few lines, but I just get the option to copy or select all.

Thanks!

Edit: To clarify a little bit, because of the whitespace changes a 10000 line file is basically split up into about three 3300 line "conflicts". Very few lines are actually conflicted. What I need to do is find the conflicted lines and resolve those individually, instead of being forced to pick one giant block or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sucked, but I ended up going basically line by line and looking at the differences, then copy/pasting into the merged file the line I wanted.

Comment: I may have temporarily swapped out to WinMerge to see how it handled it.  http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2009/09/22/setting-up-tortoisesvn-to-use-winmerge.aspx